# Сравнение технологий Microsoft

Tags: asp.net

Друзья, у меня вопрос по технологиям Microsoft. В документации на их сайте есть раздел  где описываются их назначение и задачи. Если разница между "ASP.NET Core и ASP.NET" и ".NET Core и .NET Framework" более или менее ясна, то разница между "ASP.NET Core и .NET Core" мне не совсем понятна, точнее совсем не понятна. Напишите, плиз, в чём разница, если можно то "на пальцах?" Что с чем сочетается, дополняют друг друга или независимы и т.д.?[image: Раздел Docs на сайте Microsoft]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core - это фреймворк общего назначения. Он позволяет запускать код .NET на разных платформах.

ASP.NET Core - это дополнительный фреймворк поверх .NET Core и .NET Framework, позволяющий разрабатывать Web-приложения под эти платформы.